# If $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$ and $f(x,y)=g(x^2+y^2)$, prove $x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I obtained the equation $$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2xy(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial y})$$ easily enough. So I must show $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$.

I have $$ \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} \frac{g(x^2+\epsilon^2+\epsilon x + y^2)-g(x^2+y^2)}{\epsilon}$$ and $$ \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} \frac{g(x^2+\epsilon^2+\epsilon y + y^2)-g(x^2+y^2)}{\epsilon}$$ I want to say that, because $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, the limits are equal because $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}g(x^2+\epsilon^2+\epsilon x + y^2) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}g(x^2+\epsilon^2+\epsilon y + y^2)$$ but I don't think that's very rigorous or accurate.

Basically, I need help with my last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use chain rule instead:

We have $f: (x,y) \overset{h}{\mapsto} x^{2}+y^{2} =: u \overset{g}{\mapsto} g(u)$  only if
$$
\nabla f(x,y) = g'(x^{2}+y^{2})\cdot \nabla h(x,y) = g'(x^{2}+y^{2})\cdot (2x,2y) = \bigg( 2xg'(x^{2}+y^{2}), 2yg'(x^{2}+y^{2}) \bigg),
$$
only if
$$
D_{1}f(x,y) = 2xg'(x^{2}+y^{2}),\\
D_{2}f(x,y) = 2yg'(x^{2}+y^{2}),
$$
and only if
$$
yD_{1}f(x,y) = 2xyg'(x^{2}+y^{2}) = xD_{2}f(x,y).
$$

Comment: But isn't that $g^\prime$ with respect to a certain variable?

Comment: Oh wait...but $g$ has only one variable, so I'm only concerned with it's rate of change wrt that variable....

Comment: @Peter Yep, I just deliberately showed the composition in slow motion, which, as you now noticed, does no harm to our argument. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2yg'(x^2+y^2)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2xg'(x^2+y^2)$$

Comment: Yes, I got those. I used them obtain my first equation. That is, I multiplied the first by $x$, the second by $y$, then I subtracted them.